# Scala: Initialize vals in a class outside the constructor

Tags: scala

In Java, I know it is bad to define constructors or methods which have more than 4 or 5 parameters.

In Scala, using `val` over `var` is preferred.

I have classes which have a lot of fields (like 7 fields or 10 fields).
Most of the fields are not changed after the instantiation.
So I'm trying to use `val`s for those fields.
However, the only way to initialize `val`s in a class that I can think up is passing them to the primary constructor.

```scala
class Person(
    val name: String,
    val gender: String,
    val age: Int,
    val height: Double,
    val weight: Double,
    val birthday: Date,
    val address: String) {
  def printInfo(): Unit = {
  ...
  }
  ...
}
```

But in this way, the primary constructor looks ugly. Not only its definition, but also calling the constructor is.

```scala
val person = new Person(
  parser.getName(), parser.getGender(), parser.getAge(), ..., parser.getAddress())
```

This does not look good.

If they were `var`s, I could use other methods to set them. However, now they are `val`s, so they cannot be changed later.

Is there any better way other than using the primary constructor? Or should I use `var`s in this case?

Comment: I'd argue that looks better than the alternative:

`val person = new Person()
person.setName(parser.getName())`

etc...

Comment: Oh, and I would bet that your `Person` class will benefit from being a `case` class rather than a regular class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sometimes, formatting (and maybe a bit of aliasing) can make a world of difference.  Add a sprinkling of named parameters then bake on medium for 20 minutes...

The world can be your oyster:

```
case class Person(
  name     : String,
  gender   : String,
  age      : Int,
  height   : Double,
  weight   : Double,
  birthday : Date,
  address  : String
) {
  ...
}

val p = parser

val person = Person(
  name    = p.getName(),
  gender  = p.getGender(),
  age     = p.getAge(),
  ...
  address = p.getAddress()
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the builder pattern. A builder can use `var` to keep track of the data that is going to be used to initialize, and then the class can be initialized at once. It will still have all these parameters, but you hide their usage from view by the builder.

You can even go further and have type safe builders, but that's an advanced technique and its added complexity is usually not worth the gain.

Comment: For something being constructed "manually", I'd be 100% in agreement.  But not for an object you're deserialising via a parser - it's just a lot of boilerplate to prettify code used by other (typically automated) code. *disclaimer: I'd probably use something like a shapeless HList + Iso for this kind of thing*

Answer (score 0):

You could have the Person class's constructor take a parser and do the "getting" logic inside the class

Comment: That's poor separation of concerns, it's too tightly coupled. The idiomatic approach would be a type class that handles parsing.

Comment: @AndrewCassidy anything but that. I would whole heartedly recommend what Kevin just said and add that if you really wanted to do it, place it in the companion object.